# How to apply transparent background in tkinter window of linux (not alpha)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-layout

I want to make some portion of a tkinter window transparent. I have successfully achieved it in windows and mac os using the following methods:

**In windows:**

```py
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", '#000001')
root.config(bg="#000001")
```

**In mac:**

```py
root.attributes("-transparent", True)
root.config(bg="systemTransparent")
```

But I can't find any solution for linux, none of the above methods are working in linux (Ubuntu) because it doesn't have any `tranparent` attribute. **Moreover, I don't want to use `-alpha` attribute because it makes the whole window transparent (including the widgets)**. What I want is **full transparency in the background** and other widgets to be **visible/opaque**.

**Here is an image example (in windows and mac):**

[image: Tkinter UI in windows]
[image: Tkinter UI in macos]

#### Is this possible in linux?

Comment: I don't think `tkinter` has any support for that on Linux. You might have to do some magic with `libx11` using `ctypes` but that will be long and complicated and might have other side effects.

Comment: yeah, libx11 will be way too complicated. I know about windll a bit, but no experience with libx11.